can i make firebase test lab run in specific region available from google center (Android test lab)
I have an Android app that uses UI Automator for testing. Since the app can be used in different regions (like those listed on Google's data center locations:https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/locations/), is there a way to ensure the UI Automator tests run in the same region as the app will be used?
i want to run firebase test lab in specific region

That's not possible, sorry.
